# Update refresh rate on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display, intel-graphics

How can I update my monitor refresh rate from 60Hz to 75Hz on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm having Samsung S24R350 75Hz display connecting to Intel UHD Graphics 630 on i5-10400 using VGA port. Running `xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --rate 75` doesn't do anything. Thanks.

Here's the `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with the full output of running `xrandr` - it will let you and others see some useful information about your current setup.

Comment: Hi @codlord, I have updated the question as per.

Comment: That output is showing that as far as Ubuntu knows the monitor has only one resolution and one refresh rate. How is the PC connected to the monitor? HDMI out to HDMI in or D-sub (VGA) out/in or any adaptors in-between etc? If HDMI the monitor should in theory be telling Ubuntu exactly what resolutions/refreshes it supports. You may need to add a custom resolution/refresh rate using `cvt 1920 1080 75` to generate the modeline and then xrandr to add it. Here is a good resource/instructions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Comment: Hi @codlord, I'm connecting the PC to the monitoring directly using a VGA cable, it's VGA -> VGA. My mainboard, unfortunately, doesn't have an HDMI port.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do it using the setting panel: Setting>Displays [like you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nDel.png)

Comment: The refresh rate option does not seem to be shown in the settings GUI any more in newer versions of Ubuntu. I guess the decision was made to simplify the settings and now with HDMI/DisplayPort fairly standard for monitors Ubuntu should be able to identify and automatically set the best refresh rate automatically. Of course it does not help people who are still using D-sub/VGA...

Comment: @codlord My screenshot is from Ubuntu 20.10, with all available update installed

Comment: yes, checking my installation, refresh rate seems to be shown for my built-in (laptop) display but not for either of my 2 external monitors.